# select based on random value if not exist change value php

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm trying to select values from database where date is equal to random date and sometimes there is no records how can I run the select again with another random value without refreshing website?

```
$start = "2017-08-12";
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$now = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($now. ' - 7 days'));

$daty = array();
while($start<$now){
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start. ' + 7 days'));
$daty[] = $start;
}

$rand_keys = array_rand($daty, 2);
$random_data = $daty[$rand_keys[0]] ;


$sql2= 'SELECT count(*) as total from tab where 
Date="'.$random_data.'"';
$result12 = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql2 );
$row12 = $result12->fetch_assoc();

if($row12>0){
$sql1 = 'select * from premier1718 where Date="'.$random_data.'"';
$result1 = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql1 );
while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row1["HomeTeam"]." ".$row1["AwayTeam"]."</br>";
}
```

Comment: presumably `$daty` is an array of dates?

Comment: yes that's array

Answer (score 1):

I think you can possibly do this in one query like this

```
$sql = 'select * from `premier1718` where `date`=( 
            select `date` from `tab` where `date` in ( "'.implode( '","', $daty ).'" ) order by rand() limit 1
        )';

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $result ){
    while( $rs=$result->fetch_object() ) printf('%s %s<br />',$rs->hometeam,$rs->awayteam);
}
```

Comment: Having read the comment you posted I edited the above  - don't know if this would work but looks like it should

Comment: this code returns record with different dates, I need first to check if with random date there are any records in db if there are any I want echo all this records from that date. If there is no records i want to change random date like I would refresh website

Answer (score 0):

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($daty, 2);
$random_data = $daty[$rand_keys[0]] ;


$sql2= 'SELECT count(*) as total from tab where 
Date="'.$random_data.'"';
$result12 = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql2 );
$row12 = $result12->fetch_assoc();

if($row12>0){
$success = false;
while ($success == false) {
$sql1 = 'select * from premier1718 where Date="'.$random_data.'"';
$result1 = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql1 );
   while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
      $success = true;
      echo $row1["HomeTeam"]." ".$row1["AwayTeam"]."</br>";
   }
}
```